# $\Lambda(f) = f(N)$ for each $x$ is a bounded linear functional on $N^*$ of norm $||x||$.

Tags: functional-analysis

In this case $N$ is a normed linear space and $N^*$ is the dual space with norm

$$\|f\| = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \{ |f(x)| \} $$

I am required to show that the mapping $\Lambda : f \to f(x)$ for each $x\in N$ is a bounded linear functional on $N^*$ with norm $\|x\|$.

So far I have been able to show that $N^*$ is a Banach space.

I gather that this site is discussing something similar http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-natural-embedding-j but it is instead from $X^*$ to $X^{**}$ so I was unsure how similar it actually was.

Any help would be really appreciated. (This is from Rudin Chapter 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the very definition of $\|f\|$ where $f$ is a linear function, you know that for every $x$, $f$
\begin{align}
| f(x) | \leqslant \|f\| \|x\|
\end{align}
thus, if $x$ is fixed, the mapping $f \mapsto f(x)$ is bounded on the unit sphere $\left\{f~ |~ \|f\| = 1\right\}$ by $\|x\|$! You can moreover try to find a linear function $f$ for which  it is attained, or at least a sequence $f_n$ for which it converges to.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, in the case of evaluation functionals on a dual space, the norm is always achieved.

Comment: This... seems too easy for a Rudin exercise?

Comment: Nothing is too hard for an Invisible Carrot I guess!